# Changing the login service URL in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Hi I have implemented Spring security in my spring boot web application with JWT filters. But the default authentication is happening at url `http://localhost:8080/login` . How to change `/login` to some url I need like `/rest/auth/login`?

My `WebSecurity` class is

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public WebSecurity( UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder )
{
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rest/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/*").permitAll().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            /* .anyRequest().authenticated() */.and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
}

@Override
public void configure( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception
{
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
public void configure( org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity web )
        throws Exception
{

    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
{
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
}
```

I have a login page in my resource folder under static directory. The way Spring security works is, when user sends `userName` and `password` from the form, client has to send those credentials to `/login` path in the server, so that spring security verifies those credentials and creates token. But I want to change that default path `/login` to `/rest/auth/login`

Comment: Do you need FORM authentication?

Comment: No I have a login page. By default authentication is happening at `/login`. I want to change that URL

Comment: @Virat Did you handle it ? could you please tell me if you did it, I want to change login path too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tweak the `WebSecurityConfig.java` and `JWTAuthenticationFilter`.

```
@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{

    http.csrf().disable()

            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/rest/noauth/**").permitAll()

            .antMatchers("/rest/login").permitAll()

            .antMatchers("/rest/logout").permitAll()

            .antMatchers("/src/**").permitAll()

            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**", "/configuration/ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**",
                    "/configuration/security/**", "/swagger-ui.html/**", "/webjars/**")
            .permitAll()

            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()

            .logout().addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler).logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .logoutUrl("/rest/logout")

            .and()

            .addFilterBefore(
                    new JWTAuthenticationFilter("/rest/login",
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), authTokenModelRepository),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

}
```

and make your `JWTAuthenticationFilter` extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` which has a constructor which takes the `filterProcessingURl` and I passed `/rest/login` as the parameter.

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTAuthenticationFilter.class);

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private TokenService tokenService;
private UserModel credentials;

private RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService;
private AuthTokenModelRepository authTokenModelRepository;
private UserModelRepository userModelRepository;

public JWTAuthenticationFilter( String loginUrl, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        TokenService tokenService, RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService,
        AuthTokenModelRepository authTokenModelRepository, UserModelRepository userModelRepository )
{
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(loginUrl));

}
```

After the above configuration, the `JWTAuthenticationFilter` will be executed for the request `/rest/login`.

Comment: How is the constructor call working in the JWTAuthenticationFilter class you have written? You are not accepting a Class name anywhere there.

Comment: @MayankAggarwal if you are referring to the statement `super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(loginUrl));`, this will call the constructor of the super class which is `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`

Comment: Nopes. I was referring to the constructor signature and how it is being called inside "addFilterBefore"

Comment: Also, the classes after AuthenticationManager in the constructor signature cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 10):

In your AuthenticationFilter you can call **setFilterProcessesUrl** during construction, example:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

   private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

   public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
      this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;

      setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/tokens"); // <--- like this
   }

   ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works and is a much more easy way than the selected answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement [Jordy Baylac's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4793100/jordy-baylac) answer: in Kotlin I was struggling how to set the filter once I'm injecting the dependencies via main constructor. My solution was do something like this:

```kotlin
class AuthenticationFilter(
    authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager?,
    private var jwtUtilsComponent: JwtUtilsComponent,
) : UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
    private val authManager: AuthenticationManager? = authenticationManager

    init {
        setFilterProcessesUrl("/${ApiProperties.BASE_PATH}/login")
    }
    
    // more code
}
```

then it worked very well.

Answer (score -1):

In the configure method try to add `loginProcessungUrl()` method. You can set the value in the parameter

```
.addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
.loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_URL);
```

Comment: I need to use `http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl()` ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide the url to the login page and the url that would process the authentication. This can be done by overriding the method like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
    {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
        authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rest/auth/**").
        permitAll()           
       .antMatchers("/static/*").permitAll()  
       .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
       .and().formLogin().
       /*This is where the juice is*/
       loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/rest/auth/login")
       /* .anyRequest().authenticated() */.and()
       .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
       .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
        }
```

The loginPage("/login") can be replaced with the route to your static login page while the loginProcessingUrl is the url of the controller that processes your login logic. Ensure that controllers exist for both /login and /loginProcesingUrl.

Answer (score -2):

Modify "HttpSecurity", as follows, example:

```
@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rest/auth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/static/*").permitAll().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        /* .anyRequest().authenticated() */
        .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login")
             .loginProcessingUrl("/rest/auth/login")
             .permitAll()
        .and()
             .logout()
             .permitAll();
        .and()
             .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
             .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
}
```

Comment: It didn't work!!! I have a login page in my resource folder under static directory. The way Spring security works is, when user sends `userName` and `password` from the form, client has to send those credentials to `/login` path in the server, so that spring security verifies those credentials and creates token. But I want to change that default path `/login` to `/rest/auth/login`

Comment: I thought you wanted to change the location of the actual form template. but as suggested by "Babafemi Aluko" you need to use .loginProcessingUrl("/rest/auth/login"), also you need to check the 'action="??" element in the html form'