# spring security not authentication from a post ethod

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, http-post

I want to authenticate the user from a POST method in spring security. The post hits the controller method but the user never gets authenticated. Here is the scenario

```
@Autowired
    private AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder;
    @RequestMapping(value="/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseData<Client> login(@RequestParam(value="username") String name, @RequestParam(value="password") String password,HttpServletRequest req) {

        System.out.println("here..."); //this executes

        Client ac = accountRepository.findByEmailAndActive(name,true);
        //does the authentication
        final Authentication authentication = builder.getOrBuild().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        name,
                        password
                )
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return ResponseData.successData(ac);
    }
```

This is my spring security methods/handler

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/signin").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/signin2")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))

                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(1200000);
```

Kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

Default login path in spring security is something like `http://localhost:8080/login`. Change this path following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996726/changing-the-login-service-url-in-spring-security) instructions. If you already did this please provide your implementation of it.

Comment: my own case has overriden the defualt login url but the authentication is not happening in the controller

Comment: But where did you do that and how.

Comment: look at it here>>> this pushes to the controller above >>>>> .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/signin").permitAll()

Comment: so when it gets there it should do the authentication

Comment: You have understood it incorrectly @Sleek. `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/signin").permitAll()` would just allow the signin endpoint not to be authenticated.

Comment: the endpoint has the authentication, have you checked it /signin >>>@RequestMapping(value="/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: No @Sleek, when you configure `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/signin").permitAll()` in your security config, that would allow the endpoint `/signin` to go through without authentication.

Comment: interesting... I want the authentication to happen at that moment... is there anything I am missing in that controller

Comment: Check out my answer, @Sleek. You must remove the `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/signin").permitAll()` line to allow the endpoint to be authenticated. But to be clear, are you calling the endpoint `/signin` with the token along with user creds?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `/signin` endpoint to be authenticated, you must remove `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/signin").permitAll()` from your security config.

Comment: from my attempt how do I perform authentication from an endpoint

Comment: @Sleek any endpoints that you specify in `.antMatchers().permitAll()` would be allowed through without auth. The line `.anyRequest().authenticated()` in the config specifies all other requests to be authenticated. Is that clear to you?

Comment: @Sleek did this answer your query? Let me know if it didn't.